# Uncheck a checked radio on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, checkbox

I want to create a radio button that can have an unchecked value. So I created the code:

```
$('form').on('click', 'input[type="radio"]:checked', function (event) {
    $(this).prop("checked", false);
});
```

Well, this is pretty straightforward: click on a checked radio, uncheck it.

But, what happens is that it never checks the radio in the first place. When I click an unchecked radio it checks before detecting if is checked, then considers it checked and unchecks it.

Well, this is not a duplicate as it asks a different question. It's not about how to uncheck, but how to automatically uncheck upon clicking.

How can I go around this problem?

Comment: Why are  you not using checkbox?

Comment: it is an exclusive option

Comment: Here's a fiddle. Can't answer since it's maked as duplicate... https://jsfiddle.net/1ykm4n18/1/

Comment: @Cory This is not the same question as the proposed duplicate. OP desires a way of unchecking a radio button ***only under a specific condition,*** which is not dealt with in the linked answer.

Comment: _I want to create a radio button that can have an unchecked value._ Use a checkbox instead

Comment: Did my answer solve your problem?

Answer (score 0):

You can solve your issue like following.

```js
$('form :radio').attr('data-ischecked', function() {
    return this.checked;
}); //set initial status in data-ischecked attribute 

$('form').on('click', ':radio', function () {
    var status = $(this).data('ischecked'); //get status
    status && $(this).prop("checked", false); //uncheck if checked
    $(this).data('ischecked', !status); //toggle status
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
    <input type="radio"/>
    <input type="radio"/>
</form>
```

Answer (score -1):

Your example only executes when the button is clicked. To have the radio button be checked when the page loads, I would put a `$(document).onload()` event that sets the button's value to checked.